# Hyperlink returns JSON in new Doc Window. I want it coming back to a variable like "response"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

Is there a way to re-route a hyperlink like...

```
https://api.forecast.io/forecast/private_key/37.8267,-122.423
```

...into a variable, rather than let it come up into a new window, where I have no control over the data deposited there.  This is a weather forecast and it validates the call with a private key, so I cannot offer you mine here.  The JSON is rather lengthy, but here are a few lines of it:

```
{"latitude":37.8267,"longitude":-122.423,"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","offset":-7,"currently":{"time":1407682322,"summary":"Overcast","icon":"cloudy","nearestStormDistance":7,"nearestStormBearing":166,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0,"temperature":57.72,"apparentTemperature":57.72,"dewPoint":53.92,"humidity":0.87,"windSpeed":5.82,"windBearing":238,"visibility":7.3,"cloudCover":0.94,"pressure":1014.97,"ozone":326.39},"minutely":{"summary":"Overcast for the hour.","icon":"cloudy","data":[{"time":1407682320,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1407682380,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1407682440,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1407682500,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1407682560,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1407682620,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1407682680,"precipIntensity":0,"precipProbability":0},{"time":1407682740,"precipIntensity":0,"precip
```

Your help would be appreciated.

DK

Comment: There's a way, and it's called AJAX.

Comment: I am aware of AJAX, but this site does not publish where and how to address it.   It just delivers that JSON

Comment: Which brings us back to my question...  now that you cleared it up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is using ajax, you could use jQuery's [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method, check out the jQuery doc linked in the answer, something like following is the way to go:

```
var latLng = lat + "," + lng;
var url = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + private_key + "/" + latLng + "?callback=?"; 

$.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    //get the response
    console.log(response);
});
```

**But note that this will work only if the site `https://api.forecast.io` allows [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).**

Comment: @Sudhir, thank you for the reply.  I will give it a try and let you know how it worked out...  Thanks...